# Trying to test out wp_set_object_terms, but not working

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to test out `wp_set_object_terms()` for a "follow user"-button I'm making that uses custom taxonomies.

I'm trying to test to see if `wp_set_object_terms()` works by giving it an `$author_id` term value in the user taxonomy "follow". The outcome I'm looking for is for `$c` to `echo()` a `1` because in theory there should be `1` object in the term. It instead `echo()`'s a `0`. Any help is appreciated.

```
register_taxonomy( 'follow', 'user', $args );
// attach:
$author_id = 5;
$user_id = 6;
$term_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $user_id, $author_id, 'follow', true );
if ( is_wp_error( $term_ids ) ) {
    echo "bad";
} else {
    $followers = get_objects_in_term( $author_id, 'follow' );
    $c = count( $followers );
    echo $c;
}
```

Comment: PROTip: `is_wp_error( $thing );` checks if something is an instance of `WP_Error` and you can fetch the message with `$thing->get_error_message()` instead of `echo "bad";`. That's a bit more verbose and less frustrating then telling yourself that what you've done is just _bad_ :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you have any idea what's making this not work?

Comment: Did you name the taxonomy `fo11ow` per accident? I just changed it to `follow` (note, `l` instead of `1`/(int) one) in your question.

Comment: yeah I purposely made it `fo11ow` because I was told it had to be unique, but it's all good changing it. I still don't have any luck with `wp_set_object_terms` though

Comment: where is this code? is it hooked to `init`?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm a novice with php btw